# Android : How to make a toast with counted checkbox?

Tags: android, checkbox

Hai I'm trying to make a toast with counting of checkbox which are all checked. How can i do that? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can show Toast like this:

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Count " + countVariable, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: If it solves your problem then you should accept the answer else it will float as a unanswered question..

Comment: I can't accept this answer. It need 5 minutes. I'll surely accept

Comment: what 5 mins means? Do you want to show the toast for 5 mins ? You can put your time in place of Toast.LENGTH_SHORT....

Comment: Are you kidding @Vineet Shukla. I just told that i can't accept your answer within 5 mins when i received the answer. See now i accepted.

Answer (score 0):

if you use listview with checkbox than use `implement onItemClickListner` and than use below code.

```
@Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.e("arg2 "+String.valueOf((arg2)), "arg3"+String.valueOf(arg3));

    }
```

now take arrayList of Int and add all unique arg2 in this arrayList. and after your activity use this arrayList's methods.and put toast according your needs.